# Xamarin.forms webview auto height with content

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am using a Webview and Label control on my page. I want to show the label once the WebView has scrolled to the end of its content.
Here is an image showing what is happening:

[image]

The label always stays at the bottom.

I have tried this code:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <WebView Grid.Row="0"  Source="{Binding DetailHtml}"></WebView>
    <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="TIN LIÊN QUAN" TextColor="#5ea201" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
</Grid>
```

and this:

```
<StackLayout>
    <WebView Source="{Binding DetailHtml}"></WebView>
    <Label  Text="TIN LIÊN QUAN" TextColor="#5ea201" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
</StackLayout>
```

I also tried to use a custom renderer for WebView to set the height but it doesn't work:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(WebView), typeof(WebViewCustomRenderer))]
namespace SucKhoeGiaDinh.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class WebViewCustomRenderer : WebViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            Delegate = new ExtendedUIWebViewDelegate(this);
        }
    }

    public class ExtendedUIWebViewDelegate : UIWebViewDelegate
    {
        WebViewCustomRenderer webViewRenderer;

        public ExtendedUIWebViewDelegate(WebViewCustomRenderer _webViewRenderer = null)
        {
            webViewRenderer = _webViewRenderer ?? new WebViewCustomRenderer();
        }

        public override async void LoadingFinished(UIWebView webView)
        {
            if (webViewRenderer.Element is WebView wv)
            {
                await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(100); // wait here till content is rendered
                wv.HeightRequest = (double)webView.ScrollView.ContentSize.Height;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It there another approach I could use to achieve this?

Comment: Try to add both into a `ListView` with a `TemplateSelector`. However, this is a tricky one since you would have a scrollable element (`WebView`) inside of a scrollable `ListView`.

Comment: @DennisSchröer I try add both into a ListView. its not working, webview is empty

Comment: What's the problem with the first one(Grid)?

Comment: @ColeXia With Grid , The label is always fixed at the bottom

Answer (score 3):

I solved my problem.

```
<ScrollView >
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <WebView Grid.Row="0"  Source="{Binding DetailHtml}" />
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="TIN LIÊN QUAN" TextColor="#5ea201" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
    </Grid>
</ScrollView>
```

and custom render webview to set height by content.

Comment: What does the set height by content look like in the custom render?

Comment: The answer to this question is in the custom renderer that you forgot to paste.